# Deserialising different types to single field using Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson, json-deserialization

I have a following class that I want to use for deserializing JSON

```
public interface MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("prop")
    String prop;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    Double value();        // Need this to be either a double or a string or a Map
}
```

However, I want to be able to parse both the JSON with a double value

```
{
  prop: "myprop",
  value: 15.7
}
```

and a JSON with non Double value like a string or a map

```
{
  prop: "myprop1",
  value: {
    "attr1": "value1",
    "attr2": 12.0
  }
}
```

I looked at `@JsonSubTypes` annotation, but that looks like only useful for the cases where inheritance is involved. Is it possible to do it in Jackson? If so how can I define my Java class to achieve the same?

Comment: Not sure if it's acceptable in your case, but one approach in these kind of situations (where the type can be have different json token types) is to define that field as `JsonNode`, then switch on its type via methods `isNumber()`, `isObject()` etc. and take the necessary action.

Comment: This is very much acceptable. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, I'd discourage the use of arbitrary types of data points. Having strong types gives plenty of benefits about which I can talk if you want. However, since you only talked about deserialization it might be that you are just reading such a JSON produced by someone else.

The solution is quite simply: use Object field.

```
public static class MyObject {

    @JsonProperty("prop")
    String prop;

    @JsonProperty("value")
    Object value;        // <- object
}

@Test
public void testUnknownType() throws JsonProcessingException {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    final MyObject object1 = objectMapper.readValue("{\n" +
        "  \"prop\": \"myprop\",\n" +
        "  \"value\": 15.7\n" +
        "}", MyObject.class);
    Assert.assertEquals(15.7d, object1.value);
    final MyObject object2 = objectMapper.readValue("{\n" +
        "  \"prop\": \"myprop1\",\n" +
        "  \"value\": {\n" +
        "    \"attr1\": \"value1\",\n" +
        "    \"attr2\": 12.0\n" +
        "  }\n" +
        "}", MyObject.class);
    Assert.assertTrue(object2.value instanceof Map);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you could is something like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ExampleDeserializer.class)
public class Example{
String prod;
Object value; /*this field will takes multiple types*/
}
```

and the ExampleDeserializer would be like this:

```
public class ExampleDeserializer extends StdDeserializer<Example> {

    public ExampleDeserializer() {
        super(Example.class);
    }

    public ExampleDeserializer(Class<?> vc) {
        super(vc);
    }

@Override
    public Example deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException {
        Example ex = new Example();
        ObjectCodec mapper = p.getCodec();
        if (mapper == null) mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        JsonNode tree = mapper.readTree(p);
        JsonNode internalNode;

        if (tree.get("prod") != null) {
          internalNode = tree.get("prod");
          prop = internalNode.get("prod").asText();
        }

       if (tree.get("value") != null) {
          internalNode = tree.get("value");
          value = (Double) internalNode.get("value").asDouble() or asText()...;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a slightly easier time of things if you have your different types as different names, so in JSON it should be:

```json
{
  prop: "my_map_prop",
  mapvalue: {
    "attr1": "value1",
    "attr2": 12.0
  }
}
```

or

```json
{
  prop: "my_string_prop",
  stringvalue: "string"
}
```

If you do it like this you then have more tools at your disposal to enforce validity.

Comment: Thought of going with this approach in worst case. Thanks for the response.